# How does Screaming Skull work for a Skeleton Guard?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, monster-design

One of the optional abilities for monsters in the [skeleton family](https://2e.aonprd.com/MonsterFamilies.aspx?ID=92) is Screaming Skull, which says:

> The skeleton removes its skull and throws it, making a jaws attack with a range of 20 feet.

I'd like to use this on a [Skeleton Guard](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=372), but they don't have a jaws attack. In fact, only the Wolf Skeleton and Tyrannosaurus Skeleton have one.

Do the rules provide a proper way to do this without affecting the monster's level? Is Screaming Skull simply incompatible with Skeleton Guards?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Option 1

You're already customizing a creature; give it a Jaws attack similar to its claw attack, based on the rules for [building creatures](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=995). For a Skeleton Guard, this would probably be (taken straight from the Guard Dog -1 creature)

> **Melee** jaws +6 [+1/-4], Damage 1d4+1 piercing

### Option 2

Don't give Skeleton Guard the ability to use screaming skull because they're not a "valid" choice for it.

Comment: FWIW, I've always just used the Claw attack (+6, 1d4+2, agile/finesse) with Piercing damage (which should hardly matter at that level). It's worked fine. It would probably even be fair to treat it like the Scimitar attack (1d6+2) - Screaming Skull is actually a really bad ability (blinded is no joke), so it wouldn't make the skeleton OP by any means. That being said, it's 100% my favorite PF2e ability and every skeleton I run has it.

Comment: @ESCE It's good to know that it won't be an issue to add. Screaming Skull definitely doesn't seem optimal, but it's indeed to cool to pass up!

Comment: It's worth noting that, for basically all creatures, adding a Strike option (particularly if they already have appropriately powerful unarmed attack options) is not imbalancing in anyway. Because "Full Attack" is no longer a thing, it matters little if the creature is actually clawing or biting, so long as the to-hit/damage ratios are level appropriate (and you're not *specifically* trying to avoid PCs' armor mastery Resistance or similar)